# How to switch git accounts in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I have multiple git accounts such as my personal GitHub account, bitbucket account , official github account and so on. Currently my official GitHub account is set as my global git username. I'm doing some personal projects as well in my system, where I don't want the commits to be under my official GitHub username and email Id. Currently, since my official GitHub account is synced with Android studio, the commits are showing the office email id and the email id even for the projects I kept in BitBucket. Is there any way in Android Studio to set individual git accounts for each project? Or do I need to change the `git config user.email` and `git config user.name` each time when I switch projects? Can anyone suggest a better solution? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `git config` with/without `--global` option to set your email and username.

If you want to use one single username and email for **all** your projects then use :

```
git config --global user.name <Your username>
git config --global user.email <Your email>
```

Remember the **--global** option will set this information globally to all your projects.

You can also change this information for each individual project. Just exclude the **--global** option.

```
git config user.name <Your username>
git config user.email <Your email>
```

This will set username and email for that particular project.

Remember that Git will first try to make use of local configuration, i.e. the one you set without the **--global** option. If that is empty, then the one set with **--global** option is used. So basically, your local configuration will override any global configuration.

You can check which value is set just by running the above command with empty value.

Eg. to see your global username:

```
git config --global user.name
```

Or to see our local email

```
git config user.email
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much